# Firefox extenion: Inject javascript into page before standard page javascript is loaded

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I need to inject javascript into specific webpages that can be accessible by the webpages existing javascript. I also need the injected javascript to be the first that's loaded.

Currently I am able to inject javascript into the page however, it is not loaded until after the page has loaded. Below is my current solution:

The firefox extension javascript - Note: page.js is the intended script to be injected

```
function attach(worker) {
    worker.port.emit('init', data.url('./page.js'));
    // ...
}

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: ['*'],
    contentScriptFile: './content.js',
    onAttach: attach
});
```

content.js

```
self.port.on('init', function(url) {
    var pageScript = document.createElement('script');
    pageScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    pageScript.src = url;
    window.document.body.appendChild(pageScript);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add event listener for the `beforescriptexecute` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforescriptexecute